# Run abaqus script file from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, abaqus

I converted the *.jnl into *.py file.
I want to run this *.py file from python without opening abaqus. How can this be done?

Comment: `python myfile.py`?

Comment: or `python3 myile.py` for python 3

Answer (score 0):

Python scripts written to use the `abaqus` module must be run with the Python distributed with the Abaqus install. You can do that a number of ways, and the preferred way usually depends on what your script is doing. Usually, you'll want to run Abaqus/CAE in noGUI mode:

```
abaqus cae noGUI=script.py
```

Comment: Can the script file be run from python ?

Comment: Yes, the above command runs the script with the Python installed with Abaqus. You cannot run scripts that use the `abaqus` module with a standard Python install.